# SUM lines of a file for total and make query with total. PHP MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, arrays, file

I have a file like this

```
FG  09097612 DN 6575 HL    879797
BHC 09097613 DN 6576 HL    879798
FG  09097614 DN 6577 IOPPP 879799
FG  09097614 DN 6577 IOPPP 879800
```

and I import it in mysql with

```
$lines = file("upload/import.txt");
$dbhandle = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};
Server=$myServer;Database=$myDB;", $myUser, $myPass)
or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");
$query = "INSERT INTO TEST (nation) VALUES \n";
$row = array(); // query for each line
foreach($lines as $lineNum => $line ) {
    $nation = trim(substr($line, 0, 4)); // get first four characters as nation and remove spaces
    $prize = trim(substr($line, 4, 8)); // get 5th-12th characters as prize and remove spaces
    $player = trim(substr($line, 12, 2)); // get 13th-14th characters as player and remove spaces
    $row []= "(".$nation.")";
}
$query .= implode(",\n",$row).";";
$result = odbc_exec($dbhandle, $query);
```

What I need now is to check if in the file there are lines with the same nation, in this example "FG" and sum the `$prize` of each "FG" and save only the total in prize and not all the lines of FG?

Comment: Load them in array and check

Comment: How to do? The code is good? What you think?

Comment: search in_array function (php). That said, before adding an element to array check the $nation key, if exist add the value, otherwise create a new array element

Comment: Is this SQL Server (the code is) or MySQL (the tag on the question)>

Comment: @Kickstart, it's ok now?

Comment: Sql Server has been added as a tag, by MySQL is also still there. Sorry I do virtually no SQL Server work these days. Don't think SQL Server supports ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE syntax which would possibly make this very easy in SQL.

Comment: I'm using SQL-SERVER!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this in php I would save the rows in an array keyed by the nation, and each time check if that key already exists and if so just increment the prize.

Something like this:-

```
<?php

$lines = file("upload/import.txt");
$dbhandle = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};
Server=$myServer;Database=$myDB;", $myUser, $myPass)
or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");
$query = "INSERT INTO TEST (nation, prize) VALUES \n";
$row = array(); // query for each line
foreach($lines as $lineNum => $line ) 
{
    $nation = trim(substr($line, 0, 4)); // get first four characters as nation and remove spaces
    if (array_key_exists($nation, $row))
    {
        $row[$nation]['prize'] += $prize;
    }
    else
    {
        $prize = trim(substr($line, 4, 8)); // get 5th-12th characters as prize and remove spaces
        $player = trim(substr($line, 12, 2)); // get 13th-14th characters as player and remove spaces
        $row[$nation]= array('nation'=>$nation, 'prize'=>$prize);
    }
}
array_walk($row, function($v, $k){return "(".$v['nation'].", ".$v['prize'].")";});
$query .= implode(",\n",$row).";";
$result = odbc_exec($dbhandle, $query);

?>
```

However if this was being done in MySQL I would be tempted to just have the nation as a unique key on the database and add *ON DUPLICATE KEY SET prize=prize + VALUES(prize)* to the end of the insert query.

Answer (score 0):

You could write really complicated php code to do this.  Or, you could change your strategy.  First, let me point out that you can just use `load data infile` to read the data from a file.

The new strategy is to read the data into a staging table and then copy it to the final table.  Basically:

```
read data into test_staging table (using php or `load data infile`)

insert into test(nation, prize)
    select nation, sum(prize)
    from test_staging
    group by nation;

drop table test_staging;
```

Comment: Dear Gordon, I need it in PHP, not Mysql.

Answer (score 0):

So if you need it in PHP, I would suggest using a named array like this:

```
$insertLines = array();
foreach($lines as $lineNum => $line ) {
    $nation = trim(substr($line, 0, 4)); // get first four characters as nation and remove spaces
    $prize = trim(substr($line, 4, 8)); // get 5th-12th characters as prize and remove spaces
    insertLines[$nation] += $prize;
}
foreach($insertLines as $lineNation => $linePrice ) {
    // The creation of the insert into the database goes here.
}
```

And please check the lenghts.
I think the plazer is in 14 to 15 ?

```
$player = trim(substr($line, 13, 2));
```